# increased the performance for writing the data into the MYSQL database

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

In my application i will be used the one thread for inserting the the array value to the datatable after ending the inserting into the datatable start one thread for insert this datatable into the the MYSQL database. In the first thread the datatable rows are variable in length.
consider e.g 1st datatable contains 12 rows 
                  2nd contains 1000 rows
                  3rd contains 700 rows
in the updating the database i will be used the dataadapter.update(datatable)
these all threads stop at this lines when first release fast then third release then second release.but i want release these in the number wise & also increased the performance for updating the database.this process will be worked slowly.
any one known the solution for increased the performance for writing the data into the
MYSQL database then tell me.
yanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do all of the committing within a transaction.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); // obtain your DataSet

SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(yourConnString);
cn.Open();

SqlTransaction trans = cn.BeginTransaction();

SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = trans;
dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;

try
{
    dataAdapter.Update(ds); /// or dataAdapter.Insert(ds)
    trans.Commit();
}
catch
{
    trans.Rollback();
}

cn.Close();
```

If you commit one row at a time it is going to be a lot slower than doing it all within a transaction. Give it a shot; I know you said MySql so you may have to adjust the example accordingly.

Comment: thanks for help it's working fine ,when i will be used this function using the number of thread instance then any problem for connection open & close